# jQuery Failing to Target Children

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

Any idea why this isn't working? The children of the unordered list are not sliding up like I expect..

http://jsfiddle.net/SparrwHawk/vqUgw/3/

Comment: Thanks v much guys - every solution worked but Evan's was slightly cleaner, no need for adding / removing classes with his solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go bro this looks like what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/2x2fE/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by using `mouseover` and `mouseleave` with a selector on the `children` like so:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    $('nav ul li').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').slideDown()
    });

    $('nav ul li').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some error in you code.

Check the fixed one.

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    $('nav ul li').hover(function(){
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown().
        addClass('shown');
    }, function(){
        $('.shown').slideUp().removeClass(".shown");   
    });
});
```